# Change color vector in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to change color vector in Google Earth Engine.

- Fill color: nothing(No color)
- out line color: red

This command did not answer:

```
Map.addLayer(table, {color: '9bbc57'}, 'colored');
```

Answer (score 14):

Assuming your 'table' is a feature collection, you can do that using style:

```
// set styling
var styling = {color: 'red', fillColor: '00000000'};
Map.addLayer(table.style(styling))
```

If table is a feature, convert it to a feature collection using: `ee.FeatureCollection(table);` If it is a geometry, convert it to a featureCollection using: `ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Feature(table))`.

[Link code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/88b36713fc6af4d6c7414014dab80eea)